# Authentication DeutscheBahn API

Tags: c#, authentication, openapi

I need to access some time table information from German train operator Deutsche Bahn. My customer has already set up an account and subscribed to the relevant API.

When executing this code, I get an error.

```
// Create request
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.deutschebahn.com/fahrplan-plus/v1/location/Berlin");
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <My Access Token>");
req.Method = "GET";

using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())

using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())

using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    // Do something
}
```

> System.IO.IOException occurred
>     HResult=-2146232800
>     Message=Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
>     Source=System
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>     InnerException:

Comment: Since it's an SSL error, can you try forcing .NET to use TLS 1.2 and see if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rup - Thank you so much.

I had to explicitly set this:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

The application targets Net 4.0 and I assumed, by having https in the URL, it would implicitly use SSL.